# Change the url without reloading the controller in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Initially, I am showing all the users name in the table. Once the user selected any one of the name, I call the LoadData method with the selected user as the parameter. I am changing the url #/Trades/User/User1 and append the details under the User1. My requirement is 1) In the LoadData method, I want to change the url to as #/Trades/User/User1 or #/Trades/User/User2 based on the selection 2) It should update the data and reflect in view, but it should not reload the controller.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="val in data.Titles" class="h" ng-click="LoadData(val.title)">
        <td colspan="2" ng-hide="val.title == undefined">{{val.title}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="con in val.details">
        <td>{{con.portfolio}}</td>
        <td>{{con.status}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
        <td colspan="2">Load More</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

        $scope.data = {"Titles":[{title:"User 1",    
            details: [{portfolio: "Microsoft", status:"Active"},{portfolio:"IBM", status:"Inactive"}]
    }, {title:"User 2",
        details: [{portfolio: "Yahoo", status:"Inactive"},{portfolio: "Google", status:"Active"}]
    }]};

$scope.LoadData = function(id) {
    Change the url as #/Trades/Author/User1
    Load the details of the User1
};
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.  I am using this currently in my project for something very similar.  http://joelsaupe.com/programming/angularjs-change-path-without-reloading/

```
app.run(['$route', '$rootScope', '$location', function ($route, $rootScope, $location) {
    var original = $location.path;
    $location.path = function (path, reload) {
        if (reload === false) {
            var lastRoute = $route.current;
            var un = $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
                $route.current = lastRoute;
                un();
            });
        }
        return original.apply($location, [path]);
    };
}])
```

Comment: Will it maintain the browser history i.e., whether the back button works

Comment: In all honesty, I have seen it work sometimes and sometimes not, however the way I am using this, it could be that my other code that is the culprit.  I am using this to force modal URL changes while not having to maintain separate states for when the modal is present or not.